# MPDF in Laravel can't output (inline) pdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pdf-generation, mpdf, php-7.4

I am doing below code in **Laravel 5.5** with **mpdf 8.0**

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');
$mpdf->Output("test","I");
```

It outputs gibberish/garbage values, seemingly showing pdf file in raw form.

#### Some findings

- If I use `$mpdf->Output($reportPath, 'F');` (saving it to file) and the opening that. It opens the file as expected.
- If I place `die();` after `$mpdf->Output("test","I");` it shows the document.
- My suspicion is, it has something something to do with `Content-type:application/pdf` not being set by default but I have also tried using `header("Content-type:application/pdf");` before `Output` but of no use. it is still showing `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` in response header in Network tab of chrome (also tried Firefox).

#### Some back-story

- It used to work on `php7.3` just fine, but I have to update it to `php7.4` due to some library and multiple application on a single server scenario.
- Also start using a sub-domain for my application instead of placing the directories after the domain.

#### I'm looking for

- A solution that doesn't require me to place `die;` at the end of output.
- Or some clue in on why this has started happening or/and perhaps why I need to place `die;` after `Output`.
- Any other solution.

The goal is to provide some ref. for people encountering same issues in future, since I have spent hours and haven't anything that specifically address such issue.

Comment: It would seem that Laravel overrides headers set by mPDF itself. What if you set a correct content-type manually when creating the response as per https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that I can't just rely on `$this->mpdf->Output('test.pdf',"I")` to output my result (though it was working previously with the same line) to the browser.

Because for some reason it has started to send `Content-Type:text/html` value in `Content-Type` header so I had to change that.

### Solution

I did it as below:

```
return response($this->mpdf->Output('test.pdf',"I"),200)->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');
```

Comment: it was great. way to go